# Transfer members from one telegram supergroup to another without good results

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I have to transfer the members of a **Telegram supergroup (around 6k)** from another which has been made as Backup. *We already tried sending them the link, but most people won't bother.*

I'm trying this in **Telethon** but apart from moving 1 to 12 users in one run, it stopped doing anything. I am admin in both groups.

```
from telethon.sessions.string import StringSession
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import InviteToChannelRequest
import asyncio


api_id = xxxxx
api_hash = 'xxxxxxx'
string = 'xxxxxx'
client = TelegramClient(StringSession(string), api_id, api_hash)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
origin = 'original_group'
destination = 'backup'
invited = []

async def transfer(): 
    users = client.iter_participants(origin, aggressive =True) 

    async for user in users:
        invited.append(user)
        await client(InviteToChannelRequest(
            destination,
            invited
        ))

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(transfer())
```

When I run the code, the terminal just keeps going forever but nothing changes in the group anymore.

Could you please point me to my mistake?

Thanks.

Comment: Mass-adding users is considered spam and will get both the account or group deleted. There is simply no option to do such a thing with the API.

Comment: Perhaps the users don't want to join the backup group.  That's why they didn't click the link.  Forcing them to join will just get the group reported and your account banned.

Comment: Unfortunately it is work-related, so to some extent they will have to join eventually.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
async def transfer(): 
    users = client.iter_participants(origin, aggressive =True) 
    __users = list()
    async for user in users:
        __users.append(user.id)
    for user in __users:
        await client(InviteToChannelRequest(destination, [user]))
```